# How can I parse the output of w to collect current user sessions?

Tags: text-formatting, w

I want to parse the output of `w` so I can collect current user sessions and record them via telegraf. However, it only provides space separated output and I'm not sure how to reliably parse this without potentially splitting the 'command' field into multiple columns.

Comment: Using command line tools: `nusers=$( w | head  -n 1 l cut "-d," -f2 | awk '{print $1}')`

Comment: The `w` command may not be the best option.  You could also use `who` or `users` or read /var/log/utmp directly (see man page for utmp)

Comment: @user10489 If there's a way to do it with another command that works, /var/log/utmp intimidates me. I kind of feel like I can't have been the first to want this?

Comment: @waltinator I don't just want the number of users (or the list). Specifically, I'd love to collect user names, IP addresses, login times, idle times, CPU usage, and the current command. Basically everything except the TTY column.

Comment: utmp has all of that except cpu usage, idle times, and current command, and `w` is the best source for all those things.  I believe it uses fixed width columns, so you could parse it that way probably.  I'm not sure how you want to send it to telegraf.

Comment: Collect everything, ignore TTY column later. Repeatedly do:`(printf "# date: ";date;w) >>w.$(date "+%F").log`. The log file name changes every day, e.g. `w.2023-08-10.log`, `w.2023-08-11.log`, etc.